# Blazor Webassembly: Argument '2' cannot convert from MultipartFormDataContent to System.IO.Stream

Tags: c#, asp.net-web-api, blazor-webassembly

I am trying to upload a file to the server. The client end points are generated automatically via swagger

Now If I call the endpoint, the compiler shows me following error message:

```
 Argument '2' cannot convert from MultipartFormDataContent to System.IO.Stream
```

My Razor.cs file:

```
    private async void LoadFiles(InputFileChangeEventArgs e)
    {

        using var content = new MultipartFormDataContent();
        foreach (var file in e.GetMultipleFiles(1))
        {
            content.Add(new StreamContent(file.OpenReadStream()));

        }

        Client.PostDescriptionAsync(content);
    }
```

This is my Controller:

```
public async Task<Response> Upload([FromForm] IFormFile file)
```

With the help of [this page](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/aspnet/core/blazor/file-uploads?view=aspnetcore-5.0&pivots=server#upload-files-to-a-server-1) I have created this example

Answer (score 0):

Couple of things, you have multiple files being posted in a form with no form field names, to a controller which accepts a single file. You also need to include the form field name:

instead of

```
content.Add(new StreamContent(file.OpenReadStream()));
```

use

```
content.Add(content: fileContent, name: "\"files\"",fileName: file.Name);
```

For your controller as you're trying to post multiple files then it should accept an enumeration of files:

```
public async Task<Response> Upload([FromForm] IEnumerable<IFormFile> files)
```

If you wanted to only post a single file you could still use this code, however, if your controller is fixed and you always want to post a single file, then you can keep your controller as is, but change your client call to

```
        using var content = new MultipartFormDataContent();
        foreach (var file in e.GetMultipleFiles(1))
        {
             content.Add(content: fileContent, name: \"file\"",fileName: file.Name);

            Client.PostDescriptionAsync(content);
        }
```